# What is the difference between "Per year" and "Per annum"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I know *per annum* is from Latin, but what are the real-world differences between these two phrases? Dictionary.com appears to suggest that they are synonyms (see definition below), but I wonder if one used in certain contexts and the other in other contexts?

[per annum](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/annum):

> by the year; yearly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the *Oxford Corpus of English*:

**PER ANNUM**

> For 30 years, it had gone remorselessly ahead, at about 80% per annum.
>
> An Elan bond, where the bondholder can exercise the right to be repaid in 18 months, currently yields 19 per cent per annum.
>
> With this fresh impetus, the total edible oil processing capacity, including vanaspati, is expected to cross 20 million tonne per annum.

**PER YEAR**

> We can currently get about 5% per year from investing in long-dated gilts, so we might aim to get 6% per year from the property.
>
> Penetration of digital has hit 20 % in a year, with incremental revenue per subscriber at $22 per year and growing, he said.
>
> This still leaves teachers $3,000 per year short of accountants, $17,000 short of computer systems analysts, and $25,000 short of engineers.

These example sentences are representative of the most common uses of these two phrases and, as one can see, there is no real difference between *per annum* and *per year* in usage.

As kiamlaluno says, *per annum* is traditionally used more in financial contexts than *per year*, but these sentences show that *per year* is also perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

*Per annum* is used in financial contexts to mean *for each year.*

Answer (score 1):

*Annum* is the Latin word for *year*. Its meaning in English has not really diverged at all, so it is basically just a snooty (or jargonistic) way to say *year*. Fewer people know the word, so it is probably a good word to use if you are trying to bury the truth of something under a blanket of obscure verbiage.

The cynic in me begs to point out that financial institutions and lawyers like to use it...

Comment: *per* is also Latin.  Some (not me) would look for *per annum* or *a year* but try to avoid a mixture of the two languages.

Comment: @Henry - I can see that. In fact, the engineer in me admires that kind of drive for consistency. However, the real goal should just be to communicate well with your audience.

Comment: Hmmm. Reading over my answer and my comment, I appear to have a disturbing number of people "in me". Perhaps I (we?) should see someone about that...